# Error while running hive on windows server 2012

Tags: hive

While running hive on windows server 2012 I am getting an error of class cast type. Searched about it but can not find the concrete solution if anyone can help. Sharing the screen shot might help analyzing the situation.
Hadoop & beeline is install and running well but connection to hive can not be done.

[image]